# Is pyramid_traversalwrapper functional in pyramid 1.4?

Tags: pyramid

I am trying to use this package to do the __name__ and __parent__ registration for me.

Followed the instructions on github:

```
from pyramid.interfaces import ITraverser
from zope.interface import Interface
from pyramid_traversalwrapper import ModelGraphTraverser

config.registry.registerAdapter(ModelGraphTraverser, (Interface,),
                                ITraverser)
```

but got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rotem/Programming/Workspace/pyramid/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/waitress-0.8.9-py2.7.egg/waitress/channel.py", line 337, in service
    task.service()
  File "/home/rotem/Programming/Workspace/pyramid/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/waitress-0.8.9-py2.7.egg/waitress/task.py", line 173, in service
    self.execute()
  File "/home/rotem/Programming/Workspace/pyramid/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/waitress-0.8.9-py2.7.egg/waitress/task.py", line 392, in execute
    app_iter = self.channel.server.application(env, start_response)
  File "/home/rotem/Programming/Workspace/pyramid/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/router.py", line 242, in __call__
    response = self.invoke_subrequest(request, use_tweens=True)
  File "/home/rotem/Programming/Workspace/pyramid/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/router.py", line 217, in invoke_subrequest
    response = handle_request(request)
  File "/home/rotem/Programming/Workspace/pyramid/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/tweens.py", line 21, in excview_tween
    response = handler(request)
  File "/home/rotem/Programming/Workspace/pyramid/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_tm-0.11-py2.7.egg/pyramid_tm/__init__.py", line 94, in tm_tween
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/home/rotem/Programming/Workspace/pyramid/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_tm-0.11-py2.7.egg/pyramid_tm/__init__.py", line 75, in tm_tween
    response = handler(request)
  File "/home/rotem/Programming/Workspace/pyramid/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/router.py", line 125, in handle_request
    tdict = traverser(request)
  File "/home/rotem/Programming/Workspace/pyramid/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_traversalwrapper-0.1-py2.7.egg/pyramid_traversalwrapper/__init__.py", line 36, in __call__
    if 'bfg.routes.matchdict' in environ:
TypeError: argument of type 'Request' is not iterable
```

I looked at pyramid_traversalwrapper in github and the last commit was 4 years ago.

Also looked at the changes in pyramid 1.4:

> It is no longer possible to pass an environ dictionary directly to
>   pyramid.traversal.ResourceTreeTraverser.__call__ (aka
>   ModelGraphTraverser.__call__). Instead, you must pass a request
>   object. Passing an environment instead of a request has generated a
>   deprecation warning since Pyramid 1.1.

Is this package dead? If so, is there any alternative?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [TraversalKit](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/TraversalKit/0.2). The project is alive and works with the latests version of Pyramid.

Comment: The last pyramid SQLAlchemy scaffold only offer dbsession as attribute of request object: `requests.dbsession`, the reason is explained in this post: [WHAT THE ZOPE TRANSACTION MANAGER MEANS TO ME](https://metaclassical.com/what-the-zope-transaction-manager-means-to-me-and-you/). Traversalkit is great. Can Resources objects remain de request object provided by resource factory? Thanks

Comment: I've already answered [there](https://bitbucket.org/kr41/traversalkit/issues/2/resource-class-not-remain-request-object), so I just drop the link for others who interested in.